# How to validate X509Certificate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, x509certificate

Does anyone know how to validate x509certificate in swift? Or maybe anyone have link with examples of it?

I got certificate from keychain, now I need to validate it.

```swift
let keychainQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                                    kSecAttrLabel as String: "cert",
                                    kSecReturnRef as String: kCFBooleanTrue]

var result: CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, &result)

guard status == errSecSuccess else { return }

entry = result as! SecCertificate
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for resolving those problem, but still doesn't check it.

We need to create SecTrust class from our certificate.

let policy: SecPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()

```
let trust: SecTrust?
let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(entry as CFTypeRef, policy, &trust)
```

Then we can check this for example on date

```
let trustCertStatus = SecTrustSetVerifyDate(trust!, CFDateCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()))
```